# What is the best way to dispatch many tasks to concurrent worker threads in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, python-multithreading

There is a large number of field devices (100,000, each having individual IP) from which I have to collect data.
I want to do it in a python based scheduler combined with an readily available executable written in C/C++, which handles the communication and readout of the devices. The idea is to communicate with up to ~100 devices in parallel. So the first 100 devices could be read out using subprocess call to the executable. I don't want to wait for all 100 tasks being completed, because some might take longer while other being faster. Instead I want to put the next process on its journey immediately after one task has been finished, and so on. So, conducted by a simple "dispatcher", there is a continuous starting of tasks over time.

Question: Which Python API is the best I can use for this purpose?

I considered to use `concurrent.futures` API, starting a `ThreadPoolExecutor` and submit task by task, each starting the executable in a separate thread. `ProcessPoolExecutor` wouldn't be an advantage, because the executable is started as a process anyway...

But I think, that this is not intended to be used in such way, because each submitted job will be remembered an therefore "kind of stored" in the executor forever; when a job is finished it ends up in status "finished" and is still visible, so I would mess up my executor with finished tasks. So I guess, the Executor API is more usable, when there is a given **fixed** number of tasks to be worked up like in

https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example

and not for **permanently** submitting tasks.

The other idea would be, to start 100 worker threads in parallel, each working in an endless-loop and reading its next task to be executed from a Queue object. In this case I can dispatch on my own to which Worker a new task is sent next. I know that this would work, because I implemented it already. But I have the feeling, that it must be a more elegant solution in Python to perform dispatching of tasks.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using `subprocess`?

Comment: Here's a good list of the available multithread interfaces: https://pymotw.com/3/concurrency.html

Comment: Thanks! I would use subprocess anyway to start the executable as a process. But I think  that each must be executed out of a thread, because I have to handle result from the finished executable and write it to a database. So I have to care about creating threads, start subprocess there and, additionally, limit number of running subprocesses to ~100. In total this is a "huge" administration for which I expect a readily available solution in Python.

Comment: The nice thing about `subprocess` is its ability to pass data between the subprocess and the active program - you could use a context manager and `while` to limit thread count to 100, while passing text data from each subprocess by reported PID to the database via the active program, and when each subprocess resolves, you could launch another in its place (like a slow loris attack).

Comment: Wait now that I think about it... what if you attached the subprocess code to a local server, limited the connection count on the server to 100, and instruct it to launch the subprocess on connection, write the active program such that it iteratively opens connections on that server, then either pass data back from the server to the active program to store it, or have it store directly on the server side?

Comment: what do you mean in the first comment? Unfortunately I cannot follow what you meant. With context manager you mean a with statement? How in particular would you limit thread count with while? Sorry- sounds interesting, bit I didn't catch it ;-)

Comment: e.g. `while processcount < 100: launchprocess()` repeat every time it breaks (as in goes OVER 100)